# Inputosaurus Text + jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tags, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to combine [inputosaurus text](http://sproutsocial.github.io/inputosaurus-text/) with the jquery-ui sortable plugin so that I can re-order tags and submit them in that order.

Attaching sortable to the inputosaurus list works fine, I can move the tags around. But I need some way for inputosaurus to detect that they've moved. If i submit the form after moving tags, they just get submitted in the original order.

here is a simple demonstration of what I'm trying to accomplish, I need the textbox to have the updated value of the list

html:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" value="foo,bar,baz">
```

javascript:

```
$('#tags').inputosaurus();
$(".inputosaurus-container").sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        alert( $('#tags').val() );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75c45jtn/1/

if anyone could help me solve this you'd be my hero!

Comment: why do you use inputosaurus? It will support sortable but wont reorder.

Comment: inputosaurus get all the values in separate and rerender inspite of sorting, the only way is to edit the entire inputosaurus

Comment: @GaneshGaxy how might I achieve this?

Comment: rerender the inputosaurus after sort that will do the magic,

Comment: @GaneshGaxy This is what i'm having trouble figuring out how to do, how can I rerender the tags?

Comment: wait I give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may Help. Try this..

```
$(".inputosaurus-container").sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        var val="",obj=null;
        var cnt=$('.inputosaurus-container').children('li').length-2;
        while(cnt>0){
            if(cnt!=3){
                val+=',';
                val+=obj.next().find('span').text();
                obj=obj.next();
            }
            else{
                val+=$('.inputosaurus-container').children('li').first().find('span').text();
                obj=$('.inputosaurus-container').children('li').first();
            }
            cnt--;
        }
        $('.inputosaurus-container').find('.inputosaurus-input-hidden').find('input').val(val);
        alert($('.inputosaurus-container').find('.inputosaurus-input-hidden').find('input').val());
        $('.inputosaurus-container').find('.inputosaurus-input-hidden').find('input').inputosaurus();
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Close but still no luck, the tags would reset themselves upon form submission or creation of a new tag. Good news though, I just found a plugin that enables this feature out of the box! So there is no need for me to try and knife this functionality into this one anymore. Thank you for your effort @GaneshGaxy, I really do appreciate it.

Here is the plugin I found: http://webspirited.com/tagit/

Comment: Hey excuse what did you asked me, you asked me to alert the input with changed values,its done, now what is your problem. Tell it exactly

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my goal was to be able to submit a form with the tags in the new order. With inputosaurus, it will default back to the original order when you submit a form, or add more tags after re-ordering some.